# Capitalize each key in hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a long hash that looks like this (this is only part of it):

```
countries =
  [
    ['AFGHANISTAN','AF'],
    ['ÅLAND ISLANDS','AX'],
    ['ALBANIA','AL'],
    ['ALGERIA','DZ'],
    ['AMERICAN SAMOA','AS']
  ]
```

I want to capitalize the keys of each value. So AFGHANISTAN would go to Afghanistan. Then I want to get the same hash back.

I've tried using this:

```
countries.each do |key, value|
  puts key.capitalize
end
```

but it only gives me the keys back. I want to put the capitalized keys back into the hash. How can I do this?

Comment: That's not a hash, it's an array of arrays. Your loop over `countries` works because Ruby is passing in both sub-elements at a time, but that doesn't make it a hash. Try entering `countries.class` and you'll see what it is.

Comment: You should obtain a list with upper/lower case country names instead of converting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Hash" isn't a Hash, but an Array.

```
countries.each do |name, abbreviation|
  temp = name.dup 
  name.clear
  name << temp.split(' ').map(&:capitalize!).join(' ')
end
```

This will change each of the names to a capitalized name in place.

```
[
 ["Afghanistan", "AF"],
 ["Åland Islands", "AX"],
 ["Albania", "AL"],
 ["Algeria", "DZ"],
 ["American Samoa", "AS"]
]
```

This addresses more than one word as well, and because you mentioned wanting to keep the same "hash" this keeps the same Array, the object_id (of the Array, of course, but also of each String) doesn't change, it changes it in place.

There is even no problem for nations such as the country of Éclair, as @muistooshort mentions.  However, if you have an acute character (for example) that is capitalized in the middle of the word, `capitalize` does not handle such things, and there is yet more work to be done.

Comment: Not quite right. Go into `irb` and `éclair'.capitalize` and you might see some problems.

Comment: "ÉCLAIR".capitalize poses absolutely no problems, for obvious reasons, and is the example I think you were trying to state, @muistooshort. If the 'acute-e' had been capitalized in the middle of the word, then you would have a problem to solve.  Added a note to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, poor example but the point is that `capitalize` doesn't know anything about non-ASCII characters. And even worse, capitalization is locale-dependent (e.g. `SS` down-cased is `ß` in German, `µ` up-cased is `M` in Greek, ...). BTW, `'American samoa'` should be `'American Samoa'`.

Comment: ['ÅLAND ISLANDS','AX'] is the one sample that begs the question about this, I see.  It happened to fall into an area that was no effected.  @muistooshort how do you manage your question?

Comment: I've monkey patched `upcase_u` and `downcase_u` methods into `String`, these use the simple up/down case methods from UnicodeUtils. Those don't have locale-specific issues but they're close enough for what I need and for the most part, I don't touch case at all as it is none of my business what case people use. Case matters for searches but I leave that up to a dedicated search engine. In this case, I'd store the country names in title case so I wouldn't have to worry about it; to get them into title case, I'd use probably use the ASCII stuff and then manually scan and fix exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, as usual, I have learned and improved my answer from input.

Answer (score 2):

The code does not modify the hash. It just print capitalized keys.

You should remove old entries and add new entries. Or create new hash as follow:

```
countries = Hash[[
  ['AFGHANISTAN','AF'],
  ['ÅLAND ISLANDS','AX'],
  ['ALBANIA','AL'],
  ['ALGERIA','DZ'],
  ['AMERICAN SAMOA','AS']
]]
countries = Hash[countries.map {|country, abbr| [country.capitalize, abbr] }]
# => {
#   "Afghanistan"=>"AF",
#   "Åland islands"=>"AX",
#   "Albania"=>"AL",
#   "Algeria"=>"DZ",
#   "American samoa"=>"AS"
# }
```

Comment: What does `éclair'.capitalize` do?

Answer (score 0):

`#each` doesn't modify the enumerable, it just iterates over it. You want to use `#inject` (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

Like:

```
countries.inject({}){|caps_hash,og_hash| caps_hash.merge(og_hash[0].capitalize => og_hash[1] ) }
```